# I get message "Timeout expired .." when connect to SQL database from C# App

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlconnection

I wrote a sale management software. It is working fine with almost functions (it means connection string is right) except only one function "Production plan". When I click button to perform this function I get a error message "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding".

In this function, I call a stored procedure and I tested it in SQL Management Studio, it works fine and fast (0.2 second).

Please help me to find out a solve. Thanks in advanced!
Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[SPChiTietKeHoachGiao] (@makhg nvarchar(15))  
as  
begin  
declare @ngay datetime, @thang int, @nam int,  
  @ngay1 datetime, @thang1 int, @nam1 int,  
  @ngay2 datetime, @thang2 int, @nam2 int,  
  @ngay3 datetime, @thang3 int, @nam3 int,  
  @ngay4 datetime, @thang4 int, @nam4 int  
-- Lay tinh hinh tieu thu cua thang truoc  
select top 1 
           @ngay=dateadd(month, -1,Thang) 
from KeHoachGiao 
where MaKeHoachGiao = @makhg   
set @thang = month(@ngay)  
set @nam = year(@ngay)  
set @ngay1=dateadd(MONTH,-1,@ngay)  
set @ngay2=dateadd(MONTH,-1,@ngay1)  
set @ngay3=dateadd(MONTH,-1,@ngay2)  
set @ngay4=dateadd(MONTH,-1,@ngay3)  
set @thang1=month(@ngay1)  
set @nam1=year(@ngay1)  
set @thang2=month(@ngay2)  
set @nam2=year(@ngay2)  
set @thang3=month(@ngay3)  
set @nam3=year(@ngay3)  
set @thang4=month(@ngay4)  
set @nam4=year(@ngay4)  

select ct.MaSP, 
         TenSP,
         xuatkho4.TieuThuTrongThang4,
         xuatkho3.TieuThuTrongThang3,
         xuatkho2.TieuThuTrongThang2,
         xuatkho1.TieuThuTrongThang1,  
  (   
    ISNULL ( TieuThuTrongThang4, 0 )
   +ISNULL ( TieuThuTrongThang3, 0 )
   +ISNULL ( TieuThuTrongThang2, 0 )
   +ISNULL ( TieuThuTrongThang1, 0 ) ) / 4 TTBQ,  

        TonDauKy,
        NhapKhoTrongThang,
        xuatkho.TieuThuTrongThang,
        TonCuoiKy,  

   case KeHoachSanXuat 
        when 0 then null else KeHoachSanXuat end KeHoachSanXuat,  

        KeHoachSanXuat * DinhMuc / 1000000 SanLuong,  
    case SoLuongDaNhap 
         when 0 then null else SoLuongDaNhap end SoLuongDaNhap,  

    case isnull( KeHoachSanXuat, 0 ) 
         when 0 then null 
         else 100 * SoLuongDaNhap / isnull ( KeHoachSanXuat, 100) end TiLeHoanThanh  

from ( 
       select * from ChiTietKeHoachGiao where makehoachgiao = @makhg) ct 

       inner join  
       (
         select masp
              , tensp 
              , stt
              , MaLoai
              , DinhMuc 
         from SanPham
       ) sp 

       ON ct.MaSP = sp.MaSP  

       left join  
       (  
          select ctpx.MaSP
              , SUM( ctpx.SoLuong ) TieuThuTrongThang  
          from   
          (
             select * from PhieuXuatKho 
             where MONTH(NgayXuat)= @thang 
             and YEAR(NgayXuat) = @nam 
           ) pxk  

          inner join ChiTietXuatKho ctpx 
          on pxk.MaPhieuXuat = ctpx.MaPhieuXuat  
          group by ctpx.MaSP  
       ) xuatkho 
      on sp.MaSP = xuatkho.MaSP  


      left join  
      (  
        select ctpx.MaSP
             , sum(ctpx.SoLuong) TieuThuTrongThang1  
        from   
           ( select * from PhieuXuatKho 
             where MONTH(NgayXuat) = @thang1 
             and YEAR ( NgayXuat) = @nam1 

            ) pxk  

             inner join ChiTietXuatKho ctpx 
             on pxk.MaPhieuXuat = ctpx.MaPhieuXuat  
             group by ctpx.MaSP  

      ) xuatkho1 

      on sp.MaSP = xuatkho1.MaSP  

      left join  
      (  
         select ctpx.MaSP
              , sum ( ctpx.SoLuong ) TieuThuTrongThang2  
         from   
            (
              select * from PhieuXuatKho 
              where MONTH ( NgayXuat) = @thang2 
              and YEAR ( NgayXuat)= @nam2

             ) pxk

             inner join ChiTietXuatKho ctpx 
             on pxk.MaPhieuXuat = ctpx.MaPhieuXuat  
             group by ctpx.MaSP  

      ) xuatkho2 
      on sp.MaSP = xuatkho2.MaSP  

      left join  
      (  
        select ctpx.MaSP
             , sum ( ctpx.SoLuong ) TieuThuTrongThang3  
        from   
            (
               select * from PhieuXuatKho 
               where MONTH ( NgayXuat ) = @thang3 
               and YEAR ( NgayXuat ) = @nam3 

              ) pxk  

              inner join ChiTietXuatKho ctpx 
              on pxk.MaPhieuXuat = ctpx.MaPhieuXuat  
              group by ctpx.MaSP  

      ) xuatkho3 
      on sp.MaSP = xuatkho3.MaSP  

      left join  
      (  
        select ctpx.MaSP
             , sum(ctpx.SoLuong) TieuThuTrongThang4  
        from   
            (
              select * from PhieuXuatKho 
              where MONTH(NgayXuat) = @thang4 
              and YEAR(NgayXuat) = @nam4

              ) pxk  

              inner join ChiTietXuatKho ctpx 
              on pxk.MaPhieuXuat = ctpx.MaPhieuXuat  
              group by ctpx.MaSP  

       ) xuatkho4 
       on sp.MaSP = xuatkho4.MaSP  

      inner join 
               (
                 select maloai
                      , tenloai 
                 from loaisanpham

                 ) loai 

        on sp.maloai = loai.maloai  
        order by loai.tenloai
               , sp.STT  
end
```

Comment: please show your code, substituting foo for anything that should be shared with the world.

Comment: please share piece of code in which you are using/calling that stored procedure..

Comment: So, where is the CSharp code? And really are you sure this code works in 0.2 seconds with a set of records?

Answer (score 0):

I once had such an issue, the solution was to recompile the SP.
You can do this by adding **WITH RECOMPILE** between the parameters declarations and the **AS** keyword or use sp_recompile SP. Hope this helps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx

Comment: Thanks you!
I recompiled this SP but it still runs too slow (approximately 4 minutes when I called SP from code, 0.2 second when I run it in SQL Management Studio).
I showed query plan and got message: Missing Index (Impact 17.1137).

Comment: Run SQL Profiler and check the exact query being run and try it in SQL Server Studio. Most probably you may need to add the missing indexes and try to optimize the SP